# Texmaker personal macro # symbol

Tags: macros, texmaker

If I save a macro in texmaker I need to use more often and it contains a # the # gets deleted after I click save and the next time I want to use it I get the whole macro but without the # and it's really annoying if I have to insert all the # symbols if I want to use the macro.

For example

```
 \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

gets

```
 \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1}}
```

after it's saved...

I tried to use ## like I would with the @ symbol but it won't work, the # just disappears.

Comment: This sounds unlikely. However, if TeXmaker really does this, get a better editor. (And report it as a bug, assuming you have the current version of the software.)

Comment: I just checked, I have the current version... and it really disappears...

Comment: Report as a bug? Try in a clean account?